# Harm Principle and the eventual harm of creating needs

Tags: ethics, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, aesthetics, utilitarianism

A necessity or a need is a necessary condition for something else.

A need in Economics and particularly a consumer need is something needed to be consumed, a necessary condition for achieving higher utility.
An advertisment as such creates a need artificially. If the advertisment was 
restricted absolutely in giving raw information about the good( product or service) and not presenting it as a good, presenting it as something that would make one happier, one might be indifferent in purchasing that good. In which case one can be sad( disutility, a cost) because they cannot purchase it.

As such is prohibiting advertisment( or at least restricting it to be purely informational, being boring and monotonous) in compliance with the harm principle?

Comment: Any prohibition can be made "in compliance" with the harm principle if one invents a cost that makes the object of the prohibition harmful. Even if the cost is real it is the sum total of harms that matters, in other words, the harms of prohibition itself have to be weighed against the harm it prevents.